# How to reset Rangepicker value from another components?

Tags: antd

Version 2.11.2

I want to clear value at Rangepicker from other component e.g from clear button. I try to set the state but still doesn't work. How to do that?

This is my code :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     startDate: null,
     endDate: null,
  };
}

....

doClear() {
  this.setState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
  });
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <RangePicker 
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        placeholder={['Start Date', 'End Date']}
        size="large"
        defaultValue={[this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate]}
      />
      <Button
        className="ant-btn-lg"
        onClick={this.doClear.bind(this)}
      >Clear</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: How do you try to set the state? Show you code. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edit my question @JesperWe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only using the state for `defaultValue`, so changing state after the picker is initialized will have no effect. You should be applying the state to  `value` instead.

And by the way, you are using out-of-date coding patterns for React Components.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     startDate: null,
     endDate: null,
  };
}
```

can be replaced by just

```
  state = {
     startDate: null,
     endDate: null,
  }
```

and

```
doClear() {...}

render() {
  return(
      ...
      <Button ... onClick={this.doClear.bind(this)}>
      ...
  )
}
```

should use ES6 arrow functions which properly handles `this` binding:

```
doClear = () => {...}

render() {
  return(
      ...
      <Button ... onClick={this.doClear}>
      ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jesper the code is working now, thanks for your advice, really appreciate.